# Deploy Lambda with code source from another accounts s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I store my Lambda zip files in an S3 bucket in Account A. In Account B I have my Lambda. I am trying to have my Lambda use the zip file in Account A's bucket but I keep getting:

```
Your access has been denied by S3, please make sure your request credentials have permission to GetObject for bucket/code.zip. S3 Error Code: AccessDenied. S3 Error Message: Access Denied
```

I have followed guides I have found online but I am still facing issues.
Here is my current config:

Account A's S3 Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "ExamplePolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ExampleStmt",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountBID:role/MyLambdaRole"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Account B's Lambda Execution Role Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The principal in your bucket policy is the role that AWS Lambda uses during execution, which is not used when deploying your function. You could easily just allow the entire B account principal in the bucket policy and then use IAM policies in account B to allow access to the bucket that way.

A bucket policy allowing an entire account looks like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ProductAccountAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::XXXX-account-number:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This means that the IAM policies in account B depend on how you do your deployment. Meaning that whatever credentials are used for the deployment need to have S3 permissions for that bucket.